# Honeybadger.notify() not sending a notification from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Environment: Rails 5 rc1, ruby 2.3

Gem version: Honeybadger 2.6

Problem:

When triggering a honeybadger notification from console (on a production-esq environment) using `Honeybadger.notify({})` the notification is successfully sent and can be viewed on the honeybadger dashboard.

But in my ApplicationController where Honeybadger is being implemented, nothing happens.

Implementation:

`rescue_from MyError, with: my_method` in my `ApplicationController`

in the `my_method` I have the following lines of code:

`Honeybadger.notify(ex, force: true)
render_formatted_error 500, Errors::MyError.new(ex)`

I know it's hitting the last line of the method, because I can see the output from the formatted error.

I'm guessing it's because I have it in a `rescue_from` ? The Honeybadger docs state that you can still use the manual Honeybadger.notify method.

The `force: true` was one of the solutions I tried.

Comment: there is no error, as far as I can tell that line of code runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following:

```
class ApplicationController
  rescue_from MyError, with: :my_method

  def error_trigger
    raise MyError.new
  end

 private
  def my_method(exception)
    HoneyBadger.notify(exception, force: true)
    render_formatted_error 500, Errors::MyError.new(exception)
  end
end
```

In your routes

```
get :error_trigger, to: 'application#error_trigger'
```

With these in place, visit: http://localhost:3000/error_trigger and check the dashboard again

Answer (score 0):

It was due to an issue that occurred during the deployment process to our server.